# Django: Can't run custom commands

Tags: python, django

I've written a simple custom command, hello.py:

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = "prints hello world"

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        print "Hello, World!"
```

When I run python manage.py hello it returns

Unknown command: 'hello'

- I've put it in the management/commands directory beneath my app.
- I've added __init__.py files to the management and commands directory.
- I've checked my app is in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py
- I've tried installing it in different apps and from the project root too

Running python manage.py syncdb etc is fine. And if I type python at the command line I can import django.core.management ok.

I know I'm missing something obvious, but can't figure out what.

How can I debug this to work out why my custom command won't run?

Comment: By 'checked my app is in settings.py', do you mean it is in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Do you have multiple Python versions/installations on your system? 'which python' will tell you what python version you are using when running 'python manage.py', running 'env python' will start the python that './manage.py' would start. Is it the same version?

Comment: @knutin. Yes it's in INSTALLED_APPS. Yes multiple versions and which python returns alias python='python2.6'/usr/local/bin/python2.6. However, env python seems to start Python 2.4.3 and import django soesn't work when I run env python. However, when I run python manage.py I assume I am running the correct python and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, so you have installed Django in your 2.6 site-packages, but not in 2.4.3. When running your own python, always make sure you are really using the right one, especially when deploying your site.

Comment: Yes when I run python it does run 2.6. Still not working though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that I had another project on my PYTHONPATH. D'oh! I think it was picking up the settings.py from there first so didn't see my app. What pointed me in this direction was I tried running python manage.py create_jobs myapp (from django command extensions) and it returned an error indicating the app couldn't be found. Also @knutin mentioned INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: My custom command mysteriously began to work after doing `pip install command_extensions` in my virtualenv. I was trying to retrace your debugging steps for my "Unknown command" problem. Somehow the pip installer or the command extensions module itself must have cleaned up my `PYTHONPATH` or `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` problem.

Answer (score -1):

It is because the `__init__.pyc` does not get created automatically within "management" and "commands" folder.
Copy `your_app/__init__.py` and `your_app/__init__.pyc` and paste it within the management/ and commands/ folder.