# Django admin.py Unknown command: 'collectstatic'

Tags: python, django

I have upgraded from django 1.2.7 to django 1.5.1
I am using python 2.6.6
When i try to run `python manage.py collectstatic` i get

> Unknown command: 'collectstatic'

from my settings.py

```
 STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
     'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "MYPROJECT.control.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
)
```

If i run `python manage.py help`  i get

```
Available subcommands:

[django]
    cleanup
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    runfcgi
    runserver
    shell
    sql
    sqlall
    sqlclear
    sqlcustom
    sqlflush
    sqlindexes
    sqlinitialdata
    sqlsequencereset
    startapp
    startproject
    syncdb
    test
    testserver
    validate
```

If i run `python manage.py version`

> 1.5.1

Comment: Is it loading the right settings file? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338690/collectstatic-command-is-not-available-in-django-1-6a1?rq=1

Comment: yes if i put wrong code i get an excepetion

Comment: Can you post what you have under `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

Comment: i have added the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I had a similar error message, but despite my suspicions, it had nothing to do with the Django update. If you have an error in settings (I had an empty SECRET_KEY value), then "django" will be the only app that gets loaded. I found the root of the problem by running `python manage.py shell` and that quickly told me what's wrong with the settings.

Comment: I wonder if we could submit this to the Django core team as an improvement request (so it more clearly states what the problem is)

Comment: Came across the same thing trying to run collectstatic while building a docker container, the SECRET_KEY is set by an environment variable which isn't available until it's deployed.  Still working on a solution...

Comment: yeah this just got me too. Never would have guessed from this error that I had tried to retrieve a setting from env and it hadn't been declared, so was set to None. Therefore unknown command collectstatic... sure.

Comment: Saved me a bunch of debugging time! Thank you very much

Answer (score 26):

For those coming here from google, I resolved it through adding

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

to `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 9):

If you change name or destanation of your settings.py file, you need to invoke your manage.py with key --settings.

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this issue.

First, in your question, `INSTALLED_APPS` is missing a closing bracket... so check that isn't the problem!

For me, the missing management commands was due to the `MEDIA_URL` setting missing a trailing slash. For some reason, this caused all commands, except the base django commands, to be missing when I used `./manage.py --help`

The way I discovered this was to run a base command, which informed me of the problem with my `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is caused by  **"TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS"** . The official documentation says:

> Be careful when you override settings, especially when the default value is a non-empty tuple or dictionary, such as MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. Make sure you keep the components required by the features of Django you wish to use.

And I checked the  default value at [Django setting documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) It seems that you missed an options:

```
"django.core.context_processors.tz"
```

The whole list of default values are:

```
> ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
```

And in my django project's setting file, I didn't find this value. SO I think maybe you do not need to override this value.

Comment: OK. Try use django-admin.py to start a new project and copy setting.py file to you current project. If that still doesn't work you maybe need to open e new project.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this is caused by due to the configuration in `settings.py` file
you can run perform Django's [check](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#available-commands) to figure out the exact issue

```
python manage.py check --settings=test_settings
```

you can additionally specify the `settings` file to check against.

Answer (score 0):

give a closing bracket to your Installed apps and change the `MEDIA_URL='/media'` to
`MEDIA_URL='/media/'` see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Django 1.10.3.  In my case, I forgot to register one app in my settings.py.  Adding the name of the app in INSTALLED_APPS solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is missing.

Run `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<your settings module>` and see if it fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in Django 2.2.7 and found that command here:

```
(venv) lead@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:~/Develop/dev_1_2/myproject$ python manage.py help

Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

...

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
...
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver

[sessions]
    clearsessions

[staticfiles]
    collectstatic
    findstatic
    runserver
```

because you can run this as:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure settings.py file is present in the default location.
   Or "python manage.py" knows the new settings.py file location.
   For eg.

```
python manage.py collectstatic --settings=projectname.settings
```

2. Make sure STATIC_ROOT is present in the settings.py file
   For eg.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was the result of using this in my settings:

```py
import project.settings.base
```

instead of

```py
from project.settings.base import *
```