# Why it shows Unknown command: 'collectstatic', when I try to collect-static

Tags: python, django, settings, manage.py

I am trying to deploy my Django project on Digital Ocean. I created my droplet and spaces on Digital Ocean and created a static folder to store my static files. I pulled my code from my [github-repo](https://github.com/rasheedkotoor/SocialMedia/tree/production). then I installed all [requirements](https://github.com/rasheedkotoor/SocialMedia/blob/production/requirements.txt) and tried to collect static files with command

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

but it shows

```
Unknown command: 'collectstatic'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

what should I do here?

> I checked my manage.py helper but it has no command as collectstatic

```
    check,
    compilemessages,
    createcachetable,
    dbshell,
    diffsettings,
    dumpdata,
    flush,
    inspectdb,
    loaddata,
    makemessages,
    makemigrations,
    migrate,
    runserver,
    sendtestemail,
    shell,
    showmigrations,
    sqlflush,
    sqlmigrate,
    sqlsequencereset,
    squashmigrations,
    startapp,
    startproject,
    test,
    testserver,
```

these are the commands in manage.py helper.

And my settings.py is the following

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)

SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY")

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["134.209.153.105",]

ROOT_URLCONF = f'{config("PROJECT_NAME")}.urls'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'crispy_forms',

    'accounts',
    'adminn',
    'student',
    'union',
    'chat',
    'channels',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]
    

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = config('AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL')
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = config('AWS_LOCATION')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_LOCATION)
TEMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'temp')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
  
BASE_URL = "http://134.209.153.105"
```

here, in static url AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_UR, AWS_LOCATION are following...

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=studentcricle
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL=https://sfo3.digitaloceanspaces.com
AWS_LOCATION=studentcircle-static
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17804743

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for those who checked my question.
My problem is solved as I run the following code.

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

I found it from **[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/#:%7E:text=export%20DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE%3Dmysite.settings)**.
But I still did not find out what was the real problem.
It was something about my settings file. or multiple settings files

*so, if anyone know the details, please describe it here. or in personal.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you should uncomment **STATIC_ROOT** inside your settings.py file and try this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Comment: I tried this too. but the error is still there as same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check if there is a folder in base directory named 'static'; if yes, then make a little change in the following code, remove'/' after static:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Secondly, make sure you have registered all the apps in the installed apps menu.

If the problem still persists, then try to run the following command: `python manage.py shell`

It should let you know where the problem is, if it's in the settings.

Comment: still it is not working. I think the problem is with settings.py file. I think it is not properly defined in project or connecting to another file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with replacing STATIC_ROOT in settings.py file with the following:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
```

and whenever you run the `python3 manage.py collectstatic` command, make sure you are in the base directory where the manage.py file is located and there is a folder named static.